# vector::reserve() appears to not allocate space

Tags: performance, stl

The attached code contains three calls to std::vector::assign().  Prior to the first call, std::vector::reserve() is called to allocate the appropriate amount of memory, and then the vector is populated.  The second call to assign() does not call reserve() before populating the second vector, so I would expect at least one allocation to occur during this call to assign().  The third call to assign() is used to repopulate the first vector with new data.  A fourth block in the code allocates an int array using new and populates it.

I would expect the first, third, and fourth blocks to be equal in performance, while the second block should require additional time due to the allocation(s) required.  What I have actually found is that the first and second blocks take equal amounts of time, and the third and fourth blocks run significantly faster (~30%).  It appears to me that the call to reserve() is not actually allocating the required space, but the allocation is being pushed off until the call to assign().

I have tested this on two platforms: Windows Vista compiled using the Visual C++ 2010 compiler, and SUSE linux using the gcc 4.3.2 compiler.  I have tried different levels of optimization (including no optimization), and continue to see the same behavior.  Any ideas why reserve() is not doing what I expect?  If what I'm seeing is the correct behavior, then what is the point to reserve()?

Thanks,
Josh

```
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int     len=1E8, nloops=100;
  clock_t start, stop;
  double  wr=0.0, wor=0.0, wc=0.0, pb=0.0;

  printf("Number of values tested = %d\n", len);
  printf("Number of loops = %d\n", nloops);

  std::vector<int> vec1a, vec1b;
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++) vec1a.push_back(i);
  for(int i=len; i>0; i--) vec1b.push_back(i);

  for(int i=0; i<nloops; i++)
  {
    std::vector<int>  vec2, vec3;
    int              *vec4;

//First block
    vec2.reserve(len);
    start = clock();
    vec2.assign(vec1a.begin(), vec1a.end());
    stop = clock();
    wr += ((double)(stop-start))/((double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));

//Second block
    start = clock();
    vec3.assign(vec1a.begin(), vec1a.end());
    stop = clock();
    wor += ((double)(stop-start))/((double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));

//Third block
    vec2.clear();
    start = clock();
    vec2.assign(vec1b.begin(), vec1b.end());
    stop = clock();
    wc += ((double)(stop-start))/((double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));

//Fourth block
    start = clock();
    vec4 = new int[len];
    for(int j=0; j<len; j++) vec4[j] = vec1a[j];
    stop = clock();
    pb += ((double)(stop-start))/((double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    delete []vec4;
  }

  printf("With reserve()    = %10.4lE\n", wr);
  printf("Without reserve() = %10.4lE\n", wor);
  printf("With clear()      = %10.4lE\n", wc);
  printf("newed int array   = %10.4lE\n", pb);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to profile it, but it uses over 250 MB heap memory. Why do not try to use with less elements but more loops?

Comment: @sbi: ^^ happens to the best of us :P

Comment: I have tried different levels of optimization (including no optimization).  I have only tried release, though.

Comment: @baris_a: It goes well over 1.5GB for me, but if you don't have that much RAM, why don't you simply change `len`?

Comment: Oops - the title is wrong, it is in VC as well.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that vector's source is all in the header file you can search through what .assign does. Inside assign it allocates as many items as it needs all at once. The template is smart enough to know that it needs 1E8 when you do `vec2.assign(vec1a.begin(), vec1a.end())`

If you really want to test it, iterator through each item and use push_back instead of assign()

*Addition*

Just to clarify, in the call stack to .assign() it calculates the new capacity and invokes _Grow_to (MSVC++10). In effect, .assign() does a reserve.

Comment: In addition, `vec2.clear()` didn't necessarily deallocate any memory, it may set `size()` to 0 without reducing `capacity()`.

Comment: @Ben: IIRC, I've even seen some pretty solid-looking arguments that `clear()` *can't* deallocate memory. It was supposed to be able to, but (remember, IIRC) there are some other requirements that can be violated when/if it does.

Comment: My use of clear() was to empty the contents, but guarantee that the memory was allocated the next time I try to populate it with data.

Comment: @Josh: Use `vec2.swap(std::vector<int>())` to deallocate the vector's capacity.

Comment: @sbi: using vec2.swap(std::vector<int>()) as you said shows the same results as blocks 1 and 2 in the original code. So again, this seems to indicate that calling reserve() did nothing. Am I right?

Comment: @Andrew: Switching the assign statements to push_back loops shows a significant difference in performance, I must have been smoking something when I tried this before and thought it made no difference.  Thanks for everyone's help on this!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't explain your results, but you might be interested to know that neither `reserve` nor `new[]` actually allocate memory.  Instead, they just allocate address space within your process, which will have actual RAM pages committed by the virtual memory manager only if and when they are used (and pages will be committed one at a time, it's possible for part of a block to be committed and part not).

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: This does explain part of my results: why populating a vector the first time is slower than populating it the second time. Thanks for the insight!